# How to create a local branch based on another local branch in JGit

Tags: git, branch, jgit

Let's say I have several branches in my local repository and I want to create another one based on one of them. In git I simply can do:

```
git branch new_branch old_branch
```

In JGit I can try to make the `old_branch` current and then create `new_branch`, but is there an easier way? Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JGit, the start point for a new branch can be specified with `setStartPoint`.

For example:

```java
git.branchCreate().
    setName("new-branch").
    setStartPoint("refs/heads/old-branch").
    call();
```

will create a branch named `new-branch` that points to the same commit as `old-branch` currently does.

If `setStartPoint` is omitted or set to `null` the new branch will point to HEAD.

I recommend using fully qualified ref-name, otherwise the outcome is undefined if the ref-name is ambiguous.